# Translations in variable.yml

Tags: symfony, translation

How can I have the translations in variable.yml ?
translation for subject **Hello**

```
    notification:
        agency.dpae.error:
            mail:
                subject: "Hello %name%" # translation subject
                template: "client/mail/dpae_error.html.twig"
                log:
                    type: TYPE_DPAE
                    from: FROM_AGENCY
```

<kbd>messages.fr.yml</kbd>

```
salut: "Hello"
```

---

```
namespace Di\NotificationBundle\Manager;

      class SMSManager
      { 
       $test= 'salut'
       $name= 'fabien'
       // translation salut to Hello  
       // display hello fabien
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put there not a translation but a key for translation:

```
notification:
    agency.dpae.error:
        mail:
            subject: salut # translation subject
```

and translate it when used.
Given `notification` is a part of parameters.yml, you can get value with

```
$subject = $this->container->getParameter('notification')["agency.dpae.error"]["mail"]["subject"];
```

Then you have to define a translation in a translation file

```
salut: "Hello %name%"
```

And then translate it using translator

```
public function sendAction()
{
    $name= 'fabien';
    $subject = $this->container->getParameter('notification')["agency.dpae.error"]["mail"]["subject"]; // salut
    $subject = $this->get('translator')->trans($subject,['%name%' => $name]);
    echo $subject; // "Hello fabien";
}
```

the point here is that you will have different translation files, where will be different translations for the same key. So you will have to store translations in a `messages` file, while in configuration options you should use a key from a translation.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Message Placeholders in the translation yaml files:

```
notification:
    agency.dpae.error:
        mail:
            subject: salut %key% translation subject
```

and pass the translation service to your class as dependency as example:

```
  class SMSManager
  { 

public function __construct(
    TranslatorInterface $translator
) {
    $this->translator = $translator;
}
```

defined as example as:

```
acme_sms_manager:
    class: SMSManager
    arguments:
        - '@translator'
```

and use as follow:

```
$translated = $this->translator->trans(
    'notification.agency.dpae.error.mail.subject',
    array('%key%' => 'Fabien')
);
```

PS: if the name of the file of the translation is variable.yml, you should pass the catalog as third argument, as example:

```
$translated = $translator->trans(
    'notification.agency.dpae.error.mail.subject',
    array('%key%' => 'Fabien'),
    'variable'
);
```

hope this help

Comment: thank you for your response, With this method I got this error      ParameterNotFoundException in ParameterBag.php line 84: The service "app.form.admin.variable" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "key". Did you mean this: "session.metadata.storage_key"?

Comment: You are passing the constant to be translated as argument to a service as arguments? Can you post the relevant code of your scenario?